# get session from php with Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I am using **angularjs** with **php**.

Running angular with grunt on **localhost:9000**

Running php on Wamp on **localhost:80**

it always return null when i try to do **$http.get('http://localhost/angular/projet1/app/api/session')**

Connexion.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    include_once "../inc/functions.php";
    include_once "../inc/_config.php";



    if (isset($_POST)) {

    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $parameters = json_decode($request_body);
    $par_username = $parameters->{'username'};
    $par_password = $parameters->{'password'};
    require_once '../inc/passwordHash.php';

    if (empty($par_username) || empty($par_password) ) {
        $response["status"] = "error";
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) are missing or empty';
    }
    else{
        $email = $par_username;
        $password =  $par_password;

        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();
        $user = $db->getOneRecord("select uid,name,password,email,created from customers_auth where phone='$email' or email='$email'");
        if ($user != NULL) {
            if(passwordHash::check_password($user['password'],$password)){
            $response['status'] = "success";
            $response['message'] = 'Vous êtes connecté.';
            $response['name'] = $user['name'];
            $response['uid'] = $user['uid'];
            $response['email'] = $user['email'];
            $response['createdAt'] = $user['created'];

            $_SESSION['uid'] = $user['uid'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $user['name'];

            } else {
                $response['status'] = "error";
                $response['message'] = 'Mot de passe incorrect';
            }
        }else {
                $response['status'] = "error";
                $response['message'] = 'Cet utilisateur n\'existe pas !';
            }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);

    }
    ?>
```

Session.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

include_once "../inc/functions.php";
include_once "../inc/_config.php";

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'uid'=> $_SESSION['uid'],
            'name'=> $_SESSION['name'],
            'email'=> $_SESSION['email']
            )
        );
}
else{
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'uid'=> null,
            'name'=> "invite",
            'email'=> null
            )
        );
}





?>
```

service user :

```
service.Login = function(username, password){
        return $http.post('http://localhost/angular/projet1/app/api/connexion', {username : username, password: password}).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
    };
```

app.js

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        $http.get('http://localhost/angular/projet1/app/api/session').then(function (results) {
            if (results.uid) {
                $rootScope.globals.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.globals.uid = results.uid;
                $rootScope.globals.name = results.name;
                $rootScope.globals.email = results.email;
            } else {
                var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                if (nextUrl === '/inscription' || nextUrl === '/connexion'|| nextUrl === '/') {

                } else {
                    $location.path('/connexion');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say null, do you mean empty json session or empty response ?

Comment: Have a look to your error log here : C:\wamp\logs

Comment: i have edited the post and added some screenshots :)

Comment: I think this is here : $user = $db->getOneRecord("select uid,name,password,email,created from customers_auth where phone='$email' or email='$email'");, variables are not setted.

Comment: Mathieu, it's working well:  am getting this part of code : if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
 echo json_encode(
  array(
   'uid'=> $_SESSION['uid'],
   'name'=> $_SESSION['name'],
   'email'=> $_SESSION['email']
   )
  );
}

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  http  header.

'Content-Type', 'application/json'